# Encontrar coordenadas de latitud y longitud a partir de la dirección

Tags: javascript, spring

En la ultima línea me sale un error de sintaxis.

```
GMAPS_LATLONG (partialAddress, part = null)
var res = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(partialAddress);
const { results: [data=null] = []} = res;   console.log(data.address_components);
const {geometry: { location: { lat, lng}} = {} } = data;
return ${lat},${lng};
```

¿Me podrían indicar como lo corrijo?

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante agregar que error es el que obtienes, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Dudo que esto solucione tu problema, pero tienes un error de sintaxis al momento de retornar.

Cuando quieres retornar variables en una cadena, comúnmente, esta cadena se encierran con comillas invertidas ``` `` ``` ([más información](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835362/what-does-dollar-sign-and-curly-braces-mean-in-a-string-in-javascript)) y las variables que irán dentro se encierran con `${}`.

Tu `return` debería quedar así:

```
return `${lat},${lng}`;
```

Comment: Si es un error tipográfico, solo habría que comentarlo como comentario.

Comment: gracias por la información,  ya corregi, sin embargo, no me permite continuar, dice que sigue con error la ultima linea.